# Crack sounds if I don't release immediately like wait for a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am playing with the Web Audio API. If I play the notes automatically and set the `release` right after `attack`, it sounds ok.

But when I use the piano, and set the `release` to wait until the key is released, (either a setTimeout for example), it produces a cracking sounds.

This demonstrates the issue very well.

Please fix this I need this.

```js
let context = new AudioContext()

function nocrack() {
  let r = play()
  r(0.2)
}

function crack() {
  let r = play()
  setTimeout(() => {
    r(0.2)
  }, 200)
}

function play() {
  let time = context.currentTime
  let gain = context.createGain()
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, time)
  gain.connect(context.destination)
  
  
  let osc1 = new OscillatorNode(context, { type: 'triangle', detune: 15 })
  
  let osc1_mix = new GainNode(context)
  osc1.connect(osc1_mix)
  
  osc1_mix.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, time)

  osc1_mix.connect(gain)


  
  osc1.start(time)
  
  return (r) => {
  
    let now = context.currentTime
    
    osc1_mix.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, now + r)
  
    osc1.stop(now + r)
  }
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nocrack()">
  Play a Note
</button>

<button onclick="crack()">
  Play Crackie
</button>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gc8t7nvb/.

Comment: This is a highly system-specific issue. For example, if I try your demo using my USB audio interface, then I hear crackling on both notes. If I plug my headphones directly into my computer, then there is no crackling in either case. I use Ubuntu with Pipewire for audio. I imagine if I used another audio manager, distro or even OS, then I would experience different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix the problem by adding one line to your stop/fade-out function.

```
return (r) => {
    const now = context.currentTime;

    osc1_mix.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, now);
    osc1_mix.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, now + r);

    osc1.stop(now + r);
}
```

When scheduling a linear ramp with `linearRampToValueAtTime()` the starting point of that ramp is the last event preceding the ramp in the timeline. If you schedule the ramp directly it doesn't really matter. But if you do so after a while it results in a noticeable sudden volume drop heard as a click.

Let's say you start your sound at a `currentTime` of 10. And then you stop it 1 second later. That means you schedule a ramp which starts at a `currentTime` of 10 and ends at a `currentTime` of 11.2. But at this point `currentTime` is already at 11. That means the browser immediately lowers the volume to match the volume which it should have when applying about 83% of the ramp and continues from there.

I guess what you wanted to achieve was a fade-out of 0.2 seconds from the original volume starting at the time the sound gets stopped. This can be achieved by inserting a new event in the timeline right before starting the ramp.

Comment: In the real case, I will set it to sustain value.

Comment: Also this seems like a crucial piece of information that is left out in the docs, well explained. Can you also add this to the official docs for future reference.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it was helpful. I'm not sure though what the official docs are. It's defined in the spec (https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/). But it's hard to find it in there if you don't know it already.